# Find anything but a number or "C"

Tags: vba, excel

I have this formula (below) where I am trying to find a space in C1. Instead of this, I would like to update this formula to look for anything except for "C" or any number and not only find a space.

LEFT(C1, find("" "", C1, 1)-1)

For e.g.
if C1 has - "C1234 - XXX" or "C1234-XXX" or "C1234:XXX", I always want the above function to find anything except for "C" and "1234" (i.e. numbers).

P.S.: I would want to use the find function only with improvements to meet the above conditions.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is `C` always the first character followed by Numbers?

Comment: Will C1234 always be the first 5 characters in the searched string?

Comment: Yes. C will always be the first character, the count of numbers after C could differ. The characters after the numbers could be either symbols or english letters or space.

Comment: REGEX is your best option for this kind of thing:  https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/

Comment: Or maybe, can we do a find from the second character of the cell value (i.e. disregarding C) and then look for anything but a number. So if the value is "C1234-" it will return the position of - since - is not a number

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to return in the above examples?

Comment: I would like to extract "Cxxx", where xxx are numbers and can be one or more digits, from the cell value which contains other characters too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data format, where

- `C` is always the first character
- subsequent values are all digits
- You want to return the `C` followed by the digits

Try:

```
="C" & LOOKUP(9E+307,VALUE(MID(A1,2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})))
```

If there might be more than 7 digits, you can either extend the array constant, or use a formula to create a larger array.

The formula looks for the largest integer in the string, starting with position 2.  So it will stop at the last non-digit, since anything including a non-digit will return an error.

If the "non-digit" might be your decimal or thousands separator, you will need to replace it with something else, with a nested `SUBSTITUTE`

*Replace `.` `,` and `space` with `-`*

```
=LOOKUP(1E+307,--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),",","-"),".","-"),".","-"))
```

For a VBA solution, I would use regular expressions.

```
Option Explicit
Function getCnum(str As String)
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(^C\d+).*"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    getCnum = .Replace(str, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Note that this also validates the string by checking that the first letter is, in fact, a `C` (or `c`).  If you want it to be case-sensitive, make the obvious change.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
'To create a new string from a source string which will or will not contain the characters present within the source string
'Examples of string of characters: 0123456789 -OR- {}[]<>\/|+*=-_(),.:;?!@#$%^&™®©~'" OR - combination of various characters
Public Function getNewStringFromString(ByVal strSource As Variant, ByVal strChars As Variant, Optional isInString As Boolean = True) As String
Dim strArr As Variant, iChar As Variant

getNewStringFromString = ""
If VarType(strSource) = vbString And VarType(strChars) = vbString Then
    strSource = Trim(strSource): strChars = Trim(strChars)
    If Len(strSource) > 0 And Len(strChars) > 0 Then
        strArr = Split(StrConv(strSource, vbUnicode), vbNullChar)
        For Each iChar In strArr
            If (isInString Xor isInArray(iChar, strChars)) = False Then getNewStringFromString = getNewStringFromString + iChar
        Next iChar
        Erase strArr
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Use as the following:

```
MsgBox getNewStringFromString(CStr(Range("C1")), "C0123456789")
```

Forgot to give you the code for the isInArray function. Here it is:

```
'To check if an element is within a specific Array, Object, Range, String, etc.
Public Function isInArray(ByVal itemSearched As Variant, ByVal aArray As Variant) As Boolean
Dim item As Variant

If VarType(aArray) >= vbArray Or VarType(aArray) = vbObject Or VarType(aArray) = vbDataObject Or TypeName(aArray) = "Range" Then
    For Each item In aArray
        If itemSearched = item Then
            isInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    isInArray = False
ElseIf VarType(aArray) = vbString Then
    isInArray = InStr(1, aArray, itemSearched, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 'Comparing character by character
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    isInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(itemSearched, aArray, False))
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Function
```